# Child component value not updating after set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to update properties on a parent object via button clicks in the child components. After clicking the increment  button neither of the child components get updated.

NOTE: id is purely to differentiate between propA and B for saving state

Also is there a nice way to deal updating object properties without having to do a switch statement

[Minimum reproduction](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-napier-f1sw9?file=/src/App.js:0-1066)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [object, setObject] = useState({
    propertyA: 0,
    propertyB: 0
  });

  function handleClick(id) {
    switch (id) {
      case 1:
        setObject((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          propertyA: prevState.propertyA + 1
        }));
        break;
      case 2:
        setObject((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
          propertyB: prevState.propertyB + 1
        }));
        break;
      default:
        console.log(id);
        break;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child
        id="1"
        title="property A"
        value={object.propertyA}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
      <Child
        id="2"
        title="property B"
        value={object.propertyB}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.title} : {props.value}
      <button onClick={props.handleClick(props.id)}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick={props.handleClick(props.id)}` should be `onClick={()=>props.handleClick(props.id)}`,
and for the avoiding `switch` you can set the `id` as the property name

```
 <Child
        id="propertyA"
        title="property A"
        value={object.propertyA}
        handleClick={handleClick}
      />
```

and then

```
function handleClick(id) {
  setObject((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState,
         [id]: prevState[id] + 1
        }))
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that explains it. Thank you.